# How to get rid of the moving average in the data?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I have the data y = [-10.5, -2.0, 5.0, -3.0, 4.0, 9.5, 18.0, 14.5, 11.0, 13.5, 25.0, 21.5, 7.5, 5.5, 3.5, 10.5, 7.0, 3.5, 1.5, 16.0, 20.0, 22.5, 20.5, 33.5, 27.0, 38.5, 29.0, 27.0, 28.0, 24.5, 24.0, 29.5, 39.5]

and I want to get rid of the vertical moving average trend (to obtain only the differences around a constant mean). In this context I should get something like:
[-7, -2, 2, -4, 0, 3, 8, 5, 2, 3, 10, 7, -3, -5, -7, -3, -6, -9, -11, -2, 0, 1, -1, 7, 2, 9, 2, 0, 0, -3, -4, -1, 5]

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6l2g.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB15k.png)

My idea is to fit a line on the [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6l2g.png) (linear regression), get something like ax + b and remove only ax to approximate the desired [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB15k.png). Is there a more standard mathematical way to solve my problem? (preferably implementable in Python).

Also, I think some of the differences between different values of [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB15k.png) and mean([Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB15k.png)) can be wrongly considered as part of the slope of the line, therefore, linear regression may give me an a'x + b', where a' close but different from a. How can I alleviate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 1D convolution will do what you want pretty quickly given the crazy FFT optimizations out there:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

window_size = 10
y = np.array([-10.5, -2.0, 5.0, -3.0, 4.0, 9.5, 18.0, 14.5, 11.0, 13.5, 25.0, 21.5, 7.5, 5.5, 3.5, 10.5, 7.0, 3.5, 1.5, 16.0, 20.0, 22.5, 20.5, 33.5, 27.0, 38.5, 29.0, 27.0, 28.0, 24.5, 24.0, 29.5, 39.5])
# Pad with zeros for entries before/after the window size
y_rolling_mean = convolve(y, np.ones(window_size)/window_size, 'same')
y_without_mean = y - y_rolling_mean
```

Keep in mind this will generally yield inaccurate values for the first and last window_size//2 entries since their rolling average is calculated with zero-padding, but you can change this behavior by padding with the values you want prior to convolution.

Update: Added a plot to compare to second answer
[image]

### How does convolution find the rolling average?

Essentially, 1D convolution can be thought of as the dot product of two arrays as one 'slides' across the other (Actually, correlation is technically correct  for this scenario but I won't get into that now). To get a better idea, consider the following scenario:

```
y = 1 2 3 4 5 6
x = 1 1 1
c = <convolution of y and x>
```

Every output index of the convolution array is the dot product of 'x' with its same-length window into y. So

```
c[0] = sum(y[0:3]*x)
c[1] = sum(y[1:4]*x)
c[2] = sum(y[2:5]*x)
...
```

Now, consider the fact that the mean of N numbers is simply sum(numbers)/N. Or:

```
mean = sum(1/N * number)
```

Combine this with what we learned about convolution above, and let every element of x = 1/len(x):

```
y =  1    2    3   4  5   6
x = 1/3  1/3  1/3
c[0] = 1/3*y[0] + 1/3*y[1] + 1/3*y[2] = mean(y[0:3])
c[1] = 1/3*y[1] + 1/3*y[2] + 1/3*y[3] = mean(y[1:4]
...
```

Neat! The side effect of convolution with the specially formed x vector is the mean of that range!
So by selecting x to be `np.ones(window_size)/window_size` you can guarantee that a convolution will produce a rolling mean over `y`.

This is used a bunch in image processing, when there is a lot of undesired high-frequency noise in an image:
[image]

Note that, similar to your 1D data, sharp 'peaks' and specks in the noisy image are 'rounded' out.

### Why a window size of 10?

Honestly I chose the window size somewhat randomly. In practice, it strongly depends on how noisy you expect your data to be and how 'smooth' you want your output to look.
The larger your window size is, the flatter your output will look. Based on the toy numbers provided, it seemed a window of 10 flattened enough spikes in `y` without demolishing the signal.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is what I was looking for. However, I don't understand how this magic "convolve" function works. Could you detail a little bit your answer? Also, why did you choose window_size = 10?

Comment: I wasn't comfortable with convolution until after taking a few signal processing classes but I'll give it my best shot!

Comment: I just updated my answer. It's not the greatest explanation since convolution is *way* more useful, involved, and interesting than I made it sound here, but at least it works to understand the application here.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question the idea of linear fit, I would go for the simple but rather robust solution of fitting the best line and simply subtracting it from the data to get a detrended trace:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(len(y)) 
coefs = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
line = coefs[1] + x*coefs[0]
detrended = y-line
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(y)
ax.plot(line)
ax.plot(detrended)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is quite similar to what I was thinking about when I wrote the question. It works well where there is a linear trend (or when you know the degree of the equation of the trend). So thanks for your answer, but I think @ntjess wrote a more detailed solution,  which seems to be more flexible.

Comment: Sure, there is always more than one solution and you have to evaluate the results. For you specific data provided in the question the detrended results here keep their inner relations and overall shape better than in a convolution, where data are estimated and smoothed. On the other hand convolution is a powerful method in more complex situations. As a rule I would select the simplest application that works, knowing that over-processing the data has a price.